# Is it endless "length" or "lengths" of cable?

Tags: grammatical-number

It seems more natural to say endless "lengths" of cable rather than endless "length" of cable. Why do we need to make it plural?

Comment: If there's more than one cable, and they're all super long, then yes, you'd say "endless lengths of cable", plural, because there is more than one cable (cable is being treated as a mass noun and length as a count noun meaning "a stretch of something"). If there's only one cable, you'd say "an endless length of cable", or simply "an endless cable" (both singular).

Comment: endless is semi-plural so use lengths

Comment: What is semi-plural?

Answer (score 6):

A length of cable is an item that might be a five foot bit of cable, or a three foot bit of cable, that is to say, a piece or portion of cable.

If you say *lengths of cable*, then you're talking about multiple pieces.

So an endless length of cable is a run cable that goes on forever, whereas endless lengths of cable would be a unending number of cables or cable pieces.